# Even connecting the Visual Studio to TFS via HTTPS URL, HTTP URL is added

Tags: visual-studio, http, https, tfs, connection

We use TFS for maintenance of some software that is at their end of life in the company.
So in Visual Studio 2019 we - me and my colleagues - struggle to add an HTTPS URL for the TFS server.
It seems to fall back to HTTP, but our TFS does not allow HTTP.

What we tried so far:

- remove all TFS connections (we leave the Azure Git connections we have)
- even sometimes closed this single open Visual Studio process instance
- add the fresh TFS connection as HTTPS URL: e. g.

  ```
  https://<product>tfs.<ourCompany>.<country>/tfs
  ```
- it is added as connection with HTTPS
- but as soon as it is mapped to an existing local repository, the connection falls back from https to http and the URL is again:

  ```
   http://<product>tfs.<ourCompany>.<country>/tfs
  ```

It always falls back to HTTP.

PS: On the old notebooks - notebooks were renewed in the R&D departement this year - a colleague did have:

```
https://<ip>:8080/tfs
```

instead, my Visual Studio 2019 at that time on the old notebook proposed me to change it to

```
https://<product>tfs.<ourCompany>.<country>/tfs
```

I did it and it worked in the old notebook! I even did commit/push (in Git terms, what are the TFS terms?) the changed *.csproj to the repository.
The other colleague with the IP URL got these project files and it worked for him too.

What could it be?

I did not work with TFS since 8 years, and then very shortly, so is it some simple thing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this afternoon another version and finally it worked with these steps:

1. Open VS 2019 (it is the only open instance now, no solution opened)
2. open "Team Explorer"
3. "Manage connections..."
4. Remove all connections tfs.. (but leave local git repos and .visualstudio.com for the remote git repos)
5. Close VS 2019
6. (then I opened VPN, because I am in home office, shoudln't have any influence)
7. Open VS 2019 (without solution)
8. open "Team Explorer"
9. clicked on green plug icon
10. "Manage connections..."
11. In the opened "Connect to a Project" dialog:
12. "Add Azure Devops Server"
13. In text edit called "Enter server URL" entered:
14. https://tfs../tfs
15. button "Add"
16. in the tree below is a new node called tfs..
17. browse to the proper branch/project (leaf symbol a bit like "Covid-19" virus)
18. button "Connect"
19. Now it takes it properly as https-URL (display of URL in "Team Explorer - Home")
20. Go to "Source Control Explorer"
21. Left in the tree a customer specific branch chosen
22. "Not mapped" link clicked
23. In dialog "Map" "Server folder:" was set now to "$/"
24. and added in "Local folder:" a new empty folder (in reality it was not empty, an existing repo, but in the wrong folder level)
25. button "Map"
26. Dialog "Map\r\n\r\nNewly mapped items will not be downloaded until you execute a get. Do you want to get $/ now?"
27. "Yes" button clicked (was in local language)
28. "Get Progress" progress dialog appears for a while
29. after it ended a new dialog appeared:
    [image: 30. List item]
30. Then there were pending changes:
31. URLs in sln and only few csproj files (of a lot more)
32. commited and pushed these changes
33. Now it seems to work - hurray

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Things to do after you rename the URL of your account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793597/things-to-do-before-and-after-you-rename-the-url-of-your-team-foundati).

You also need to update Git remotes:

- In the web user interface, click the Clone button and copy the new Git URL.
- Open a command prompt window. Change the directory to the Git repository.
- Update the remote URL. Assuming that the remote is named "origin," the command would be git remote set-url origin <url_copied_from_web>.

Comment: I am not sure if your answer fits, it mentions <company>.visualstudio.com - there we have the git repositories that are not the problem, but our TFS reporsitories are (locally in our company!?) under <product>tfs.<company>.<country>! I will ask the colleague to check your answer, if some have a problem again. Anyway thanks for your effort.